# Strange JVM Error with ICS

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native, android-ndk

I am gaving a strange problem with a code. 
The task is quite simple, from native code I call a java function, which gets a param from prefs, and returns to c++, the method is with no params and returns a string.

Even stranger, it runs nicely on the first run, but the second time I call the whole native procedure from java when the c++ routine tries to contact the java method it crashes. which tells me it's a memory corruption but I have no idea why it happens.

Ok. So, in the onLoad method in the lib I make a ref to the javaVM, like so :

```
JNIEnv *env;
LOGI("JNI_OnLoad called");
if (vm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
    LOGE("Failed to get the environment using GetEnv()");
    return -1;
}
MY_NAMESPACE::VMHandler::getInstance()->init(env);
```

Init actually just saves the pointer in the running instance and give's me no problems in the later run since I call it multiple times.

next, I call the java method, getTime()

```
LOGE("get TIME called");

//getting a pointer to the VM
JNIEnv * env = VMHandler::getInstance()->getJava();
LOGE("1");
if (env==NULL) {
    LOGE("1.0");
}else{
    LOGE("1.0 OK");
}

if (dao==NULL) {
    LOGE("1.1");
}else{
    LOGE("1.1 OK");

}
if (jgetTime==NULL) {
    LOGE("1.2");
}else{
    LOGE("1.2 OK");

}

jstring time = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(dao,jgetTime);
LOGE("2");
```

Interestingly enough, I get the following log from first run :

```
E/app-cpp(7121): 1
E/app-cpp(7121): 1.0 OK
E/app-cpp(7121): 1.1 OK
E/app-cpp(7121): 1.2 OK
E/Settings(7121): Java received : getTime()
E/Settings(7121): Java returning : 1341250295
```

and then second run...

```
E/app-cpp(1941): get TIME called
E/app-cpp(1941): 1
E/app-cpp(1941): 1.0 OK
E/app-cpp(1941): 1.1 OK
E/app-cpp(1941): 1.2 OK
A/libc(1941): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000008d (code=1)
```

and the complete dump is :

```
07-02 17:08:20.948: E/my-cpp(1941): 1
07-02 17:08:20.958: E/my-cpp(1941): 1.0 OK
07-02 17:08:20.958: E/my-cpp(1941): 1.1 OK
07-02 17:08:20.958: E/my-cpp(1941): 1.2 OK
07-02 17:08:20.958: A/libc(1941): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000008d (code=1)
07-02 17:08:20.967: D/debug(1941): LoaderCalled!
07-02 17:08:21.298: D/dalvikvm(78): GC_CONCURRENT freed 296K, 13% free 11332K/12935K, paused 4ms+28ms
07-02 17:08:21.407: I/Process(78): Sending signal. PID: 1941 SIG: 3
07-02 17:08:21.407: I/dalvikvm(1941): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-02 17:08:21.417: I/dalvikvm(1941): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-02 17:08:21.477: D/debug(1941): mSwitcher:android.widget.TextSwitcher@41495318
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:4.0.4/MR1/302030:eng/test-keys'
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844): pid: 1941, tid: 2162  >>> com.myapp <<<
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000008d
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  r0 00238040  r1 1d200222  r2 00000001  r3 0000008c
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  r4 4a5db590  r5 004ea2e8  r6 4a5db590  r7 49cc1bc4
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  r8 49cc1bc4  r9 49ab4f64  10 495f752c  fp 49cc1bdc
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  ip 40003108  sp 49cc17b8  lr 4a02a79b  pc 4a029fb0  cpsr 00000030
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  d0  42c8000042b6aa73  d1  3ff0000000b23680
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  d2  3ff0000000000000  d3  4197d78400000000
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  d4  3ff0000000000000  d5  4028000000000000
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  d6  00c31fe000000000  d7  0000005b4e8b3a94
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  d8  3f8000003f800000  d9  43d2000000000000
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  d10 000000004479f062  d11 0000000000000000
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
07-02 17:08:21.487: I/DEBUG(3844):  scr 20000012
07-02 17:08:21.717: I/ActivityManager(78): Displayed com.myapp/.ui.activities.Loader: +831ms
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844):          #00  pc 00367fb0  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/libwrapper.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv16CallObjectMethodEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz)
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844):          #01  lr 4a02a79b  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/libwrapper.so
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): code around pc:
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): 4a029f90 1c0347a0 b0041c18 46c0bd10 b510b40c  .G.........F....
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): 4a029fa0 9001b084 ab079100 9b019302 238c681a  .............h.#
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): 4a029fb0 980158d4 9a069900 47a09b02 93031c03  .X.........G....
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): 4a029fc0 1c189b03 bc10b004 b002bc08 46c04718  .............G.F
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): 4a029fd0 b510b40c 9001b084 ab079100 9b019302  ................
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): code around lr:
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): 4a02a778 1c112006 f3e91c1a 4b40fbe7 681a58e3  . ........@K.X.h
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): 4a02a788 58e34b43 9904681b 1c111c08 f7ff1c1a  CK.X.h..........
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): 4a02a798 1c03fc01 4b439305 1c1a447b 447b4b42  ......CK{D..BK{D
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): 4a02a7a8 1c112006 f3e91c1a 9a04fbcf 1c109b05  . ..............
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): 4a02a7b8 22001c19 fbaaf7f5 93061c03 447b4b3b  ..."........;K{D
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844): stack:
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc1778  00000000  
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc177c  0038d96c  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc1780  0023c108  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc1784  49cc1884  
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc1788  4a5d28d0  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/libwrapper.so
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc178c  001a1f20  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.437: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc1790  001a1f28  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc1794  001a1f28  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc1798  001c7580  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc179c  001c7588  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17a0  001c7588  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17a4  00483ccc  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17a8  0023c540  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17ac  4004c4b0  
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17b0  df0027ad  
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17b4  00000000  
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844): #00 49cc17b8  1d200222  
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17bc  00238040  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17c0  49cc17d4  
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17c4  4a5db590  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/libwrapper.so
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17c8  4a5db590  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/libwrapper.so
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17cc  4a02a79b  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/libwrapper.so
07-02 17:08:22.457: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17d0  44e313c0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17d4  44e313c0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17d8  49cc1bc4  
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17dc  0023c710  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17e0  495f752c  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.myapp-1.apk@classes.dex
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17e4  0023c108  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17e8  00238040  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17ec  4a5db590  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/libwrapper.so
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17f0  49cc1bc4  
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17f4  0023c108  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17f8  0023c108  [heap]
07-02 17:08:22.467: I/DEBUG(3844):     49cc17fc  4a3c579f  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/libwrapper.so
07-02 17:08:27.908: I/BootReceiver(78): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_07 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
```

Comment: jgetTime is not NULL, but is it valid? It would be interesting to see your results if you fetch it immediately prior to calling it.

Comment: I just tried getting a handle on the method, but I just got the exception a bit higher, which is when I say getMethod...
Strange? could mu env be corrupted??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that the following:
!! I cached the JNIEnv pointer provided by the javaVM, in the onload method. !!

and this pointer is invalidated per thread (not exactly clear what this meant when I ran on it on the net. )

but it got me thinking when I got an error trying to get a pointer just before I call the method.
So I recache the JNIEnv on every function call and rereference all the methods and classes.
in essence just re-calling my

`MY_NAMESPACE::VMHandler::getInstance()->init(env);`

method did the trick...

an interesting thing to notice about references is the following :

> A local is only usable from the thread it was originally handed to,
> and is valid until either an explicit call to DeleteLocalRef() or,
> more commonly, until you return from your native method.  When a
> native method returns, all local references are automatically deleted.

Found :
[Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html)

But I guess in my case the JNIenv pointer was invalidated...